# How to use Bayes Theorem by tree diagram

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

**Question**

> An investment company analyses stocks and predicts whether their price will go up or down. So
>   far, half of the stocks analysed by the company have gone up, $3/4$ of the stocks that went up were
>   correctly predicted to go up, and $2/5$ of the stocks that went down were incorrectly predicted to
>   go up. Suppose that the company tells you that it will go up. Compute the probability that the
>   stock will indeed go up.

**My Answer**

I have drawn a tree diagram for this question based on the stocks gone up and gone down. For "gone up", $1/2$ stocks. For "gone down", $1/2$ stocks. After drawing "gone up" and "down", I also drew "correctly go up" and "incorrectly go down" for the stocks that have gone up. I also draw "correctly go down" and "incorrectly go down" for the stocks that have gone down.

My answer for this question will be $1/2 \cdot 3/4$. It seems not correct since I didn't use the Bayes' Theorem. Can I have some tips on this question. I think I have some misunderstanding for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $N$ be the number of stocks the company analyzed. We are told that $\frac N2$ stocks went up. Of those $3/4$ were predicted to go up, and $1/4$ were not predicted to go up. That means:

- $\dfrac 34\dfrac N2 = \dfrac {3N}8$ stocks were predicted to go up and did go up.
- $\dfrac 14\dfrac N2 = \dfrac N8$ stocks were not predicted to go up, but went up.

The other $\frac N2$ stocks did not go up. Of these $\frac 25$ were predicted to go up. So we also have

- $\dfrac 25\dfrac N2 = \dfrac N5$ stocks were predicted to go up but did not go up.
- $\dfrac 35\dfrac N2 = \dfrac {3N}{10}$ stocks were not predicted to go up, and did not go up.

You have a stock that was predicted to rise. That means it is either one of the $\frac {3N}8$ stocks predicted to rise which did rise. Or it is one of the $\frac N5$ stocks predicted to rise but did not rise. The total number of stocks predicted to rise is $$\dfrac {3N}8 + \dfrac N5 = \frac{23N}{40}$$
The probability of such a stock actually rising is the ratio

$$\dfrac{\dfrac {3N}8}{\phantom{M}\dfrac{23N}{40}\phantom{M}} = \dfrac {15}{23}$$

This is also what Bayes Theorem tells you, but I find it better to work things out carefully until you understand what is going on, and only when you are comfortable with that, to resort to applying memorized formulas.

Comment: Thanks, my tree diagram is wrong.